# Custom template for different post types

Tags: posts, templates, content

I'm struggling to get my head around the correct terminology for posts/templates etc which is making it difficult to find what I'm looking for in Google/on here.

Basically, I'd like a user to be able to select from a drop down in the new post page, and this will prepopulate the posts box with a "template" the author can then fill in.

For example, if they select "Review", it'll have a space for an image, some text, a link to something like Soundcloud, and then a Star rating at the bottom.

If they select "Top 50 albums", it'll populate with 50 boxes, all ready for the user to select album art, youtube link etc etc.

Is this something that natively exists in Wordpress? Is there a plug in for such functionality or can I write this from scratch?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Hello Carl. What you want is obviously not in WordPress core (for me it is obvious). Plugin recommendation is off-topic in this site. And yes, you can write it from scratch but sincerely your question is too boar and it may require too much work to be posted in a answer. If you can break down into specific problems it could be easier to answer.

Comment: While technically off-topic, the easy answer is Elliot Condon's excellent Advanced Custom Fields plug-in.  I have used it with dozens of sites and it works wonderfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend Custom Post Types : http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types

You can add appropriate meta boxes to each post type : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

You can define specific front end templates for each post type : http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Type_Templates

Instead of a dropdown, you would have distinct menu items for each "thing" ( Review, Albums, etc ).

Comment: For non-programming solutions to creating CPTs, check out the Pods framework: http://pods.io/docs/learn/what-is-pods/